# F# unable to create NUnit tests from TestFixtureSource and class with multiple parameter constructor

Tags: f#, nunit

I am new in F# and I wonder whether is there a possibility (unsing NUnit) to construct a test class  multiple parameters in its constructor with some similar construction - following end up with
Message:
OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found

```
// if data with one parameter, no problem to run the tests
// the data not only the constants at the compile time, so need to work TestFixtureSoource attribute.
type SimpleFixtureArgs =
    static member Source = [| (String.Empty, String.Empty); ("hello", "hello") |]

[<TestFixtureSource(typeof<SimpleFixtureArgs>, "Source")>]
type ``simple tests class``(text, text2) =
    [<Test>]
    member this.``simple test``() =
        let expexted = text
        let actual = text2
        Assert.AreEqual(expexted, actual)
```

Since removing the one parameter (e.g. the text2) and having appropriate one-parameter TestFixtureSource it started to work...

So the question is how to write the NUnit test to work with TestFixtureSource with multiple parameters?

TIA,
Mojmir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual items of text fixture source should be object arrays or derive from the TestFixtureParameters class ([NUnit documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testfixturesource.html)). But tuple is not an object array - it's a single object. So change source property to return `IEnumerbale` (or array) of arrays:

```
type SimpleFixtureArgs =
    static member Source = seq {
        [| String.Empty; String.Empty|]
        [| "hello"; "hello"|]
    }
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot, thanks.  It needed to add yield keywords to finish the run tests   type SimpleFixtureArgs =
    static member Source =
        seq {
            yield [| String.Empty; String.Empty |]
            yield [| "hello"; "hello" |]
        }

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm using the latest F# 4.7 which has implicit yields feature

Comment: thanks for the note, as I am just learning the language, it was useful for me to know about implicit yield. Actually I have test project in the .NET Core 3.1. just tried it and it is working. So when it originally not worked, it must have be caused by something else...

Answer (score 0):

Later, I needed to deal with different types of parameters.
There is slightly modified code in F# from the previous answer, which worked for me.

```
    type SimpleFixtureArgs2 =
    static member Source : seq<obj []> =
        seq {
            yield [| String.Empty; String.Empty; 1; 1 |]
            yield [| "hello"; "hello"; 2; 2 |]
        }

[<TestFixtureSource(typeof<SimpleFixtureArgs2>, "Source")>]
type ``simple tests2 class``(text1, text2, num1, num2) =
    [<Test>]
    member this.``simple strings and integers test``() =
        let expextedText = text1
        let actualText = text2
        Assert.AreEqual(expextedText, actualText)

        Assert.AreEqual(num1, num2)
```